# Trying to catching data with json, it is returning null

Tags: ios, json, xcode5

I am new in Xcode, iOS and json, so i am trying get a data from my server but when I call the action it is returning `null`. Please help me with this?

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)buscardados:(id)sender {

    NSURL *local = [NSURL URLWithString:panhacaminho];

    NSData *datas = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:local];

    json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: datas options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    dados=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<json.count; i++)
    {
        entrantsArray = [[[json objectForKey:@"ID"] allValues] objectAtIndex:i];


    }
    NSLog(@" Identificacao: %@", entrantsArray);

}
```

Data in Json:

{"aviao":[{"ID":"1","NOME":"ART580","LOGO":null,"NOMECOMPAINHA":"TACV","CAPACIDADE":"250","DATE_LOG":"2013-12-10 17:02:34","vooses":[{"ID":"1","CODIGO":"V534PS","ID_ROTA":"1","ID_AVIAO":"1","AEROPORTOPARTIDA":"1","AEROPORTOCHEGADA":"2","DATAPARTIDA":"2013-08-08","DATACHEGADA":"2013-08-09","HORAPARTIDA":"23:45:00","HORACHEGADA":"02:20:00","TIPOVOO":"Nacional","ESTADO":"0","DATE_LOG":"2013-12-10 17:02:47"}

i want to get those atributs in variables

Comment: here is the path of "panhacaminho" http://192.168.1.110/238cv/restfullapi.php/api/aviao"

Comment: Do you know the meaning of 192.168.1.110? It's not going to work except for your colleagues on the same network.

Comment: i know that....its the ip server that im going to cath my database

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out whether you received any data and what the structure of your data is, by calling NSLog (@"%@", json).

And you need to seriously learn the basics of NSDictionary, NSArray and so on because the code that you wrote shows that you know nothing of it. Xcode has all the documentation for these classes that you need.

Comment: when i do the NSLog(@"%@",json) he shows the data, but i think the problem is when im going to put it into a NsDictionary

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the response you get from your server. If you have something like:

EDITED HERE with your answer information:

```
{"aviao": [{"ID":"1","NOME":"ART580","LOGO":null,"NOMECOMPAINHA":"TACV","CAPACIDA‌​DE":"250","DATE_LOG":"2013-12-10 17:02:34",...
```

You may try this one:

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

if (!json) {
   NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
   NSArray *arrayTemp = json[@"aviao"]
   for(NSDictionary *item in arrayTemp) {
      NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
      //or, to check some values....
      NSLog(@"ID:%@  NOME:%@ LOGO:%@",item[@"ID"],item[@"NOME"],item[@"LOGO"]);
   }
}
```

Comment: {"aviao":[{"ID":"1","NOME":"ART580","LOGO":null,"NOMECOMPAINHA":"TACV","CAPACIDADE":"250","DATE_LOG":"2013-12-10 17:02:34","vooses":[{"ID":"1","CODIGO":"V534PS","ID_ROTA":"1"

Comment: where "aviao" is my table and content some instances

Comment: like this he returns on nslog just "aviao"

Comment: well when i do that he returns null, inclusive the json and the array temp....please help me!! i need he to fetch the data from aviao and then put everything on a array

Comment: Have you checked what 'json' variable returns? Just after calling the JsonObjectWithData...?